# WindowsIdentity of Client User

Tags: c#, client-server, windows-identity

I am programming a web application for a company, they require that the user should not enter any username and password, the user should be allowed to login to the system by their windows identity.

i have tried WindowsIdenity.GetCurrent() , its working on if the application is on the client.

How do i get the WindowsIdenitiy of the Client User to be sent to the server.

Comment: In a page: User.Identity.Name

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer has a mechanism for transferring the client's windows credentials to the server. You'll need to make your clients use IE, and of course make sure they are on the same domain forest as the server.

You can read [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1152237.aspx) a little about using integrated windows authentication with ASP.NET .

Comment: User.Idenitity.name is always empty srting

Comment: Have you set up the integrated authentication properly?